# Disable function call from code base

Tags: c++

Based on a poorly stated and recently deleted SO question ("Is it possible to call a function without calling it?") I have a similar question, hopefully put in a more logical perspective.

Is it possible / what are the best practices, to disable a function call from a codebase ? By disabling I don't mean greping through the whole code to manually comment out the function (which is a valid but somewhat tedious task). The only ways I can think of are

1. Returning as soon as entering function

   ```
   ret_type foo()
   {
       return ret_type();
       // actual implementation is not allowed to run
   }
   ```

which would be a bit dangerous when the return code is used by caller functions.

1. Replace the declaration with an idle macro

   ```
   ret_type foo();
   #define foo() do { void; } while (0);
   ```

Is there a standard way, maybe a compiler hook, a pragma directive to do this and if not what are some other ways?

Comment: What about throwing an exception??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well it would imply altering the return type and if I don't catch it ... then there are some more problems. By disabling I mean 'as if it's never written' and in this case throwing is not the hack we're after. ('Don't misuse exceptions this way' you said, but I'm not allowed to quote you I think)

Comment: _''Don't misuse exceptions this way' you said'_ Oh, did I? Don't remember the context actually, but might well be I said this. Hmm' I'm not sure about your preprocessor hack, at least I'd put surrounding braces to the replacement: `{ do { void; } while (0); }`. But yes, any decent c++ compiler should optimize any calls out seeing this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard way, maybe a compiler hook, a pragma directive to do this and if not what are some other ways?

Let's just think for a minute, together. Let's consider two main cases:

- the function returns `void`
- the function returns something

In the first case you can simply take the body of the function and comment it out. BOOM: disabled.

In the second case you have a return value. Let's consider other two cases:

- the returned value is used
- the returned value is not used

In the first case you should ask yourself: can I return a dummy value and get away with it? If the answer is yes, then do so. If not, then you can't do anything about it except refactor your entire code.

In the second case you can comment it out, but why you are returning a value in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it's logical that only a certain type of functions can be disabled, so it's more of a design type of thing. When I can define enums as return values, I always use a `no_action` member ... just in case. I think you've covered it though.